# How do I detect if a block is avaialble in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am writing a module in which I would like to include another block, if it is available, but include a different one if the module containing that block is not installed. Something like this:

```
if(block_exists($blockname)$this->getLayout()->createBlock($blockname);
else $this->getLayout()->createBlock($otherblock);
```

So, how do I detect whether a specific block or module is installed?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found in mage/core/model/layout.php, where the _getBlockInstance detects whether a block exists and can be used. For you, your block_exists function would be this:

```
function block_exists($block){
    if(
        class_exists($block, false) || mageFindClassFile($block) ||
        ($block = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($block) &&
            (class_exists($block, false) || mageFindClassFile($block))
        )
    ) return true;
    return false;
}
```